# Add a prefix to all rows in R

Tags: r, syntax, prefix

I am trying to add a prefix `end` to all rows in a col `ensnp` in a dataframe `chrs`:

```
 Name    endsnp
Bov001   Bov001
Bov002   Bov001
```

My expected output must be like that:

```
 Name     endsnp
Bov001   endBov001
Bov002   endBov001
```

I have tried `chrs <- transform(chrs, endsnp = sprintf("end", endsnp))`, but I get this output:

```
 Name     endsnp
Bov001     end
Bov002     end
```

Any ideas about my error? Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use `paste0` to combine strings.

For example,

```
chrs$endsnp = paste0('end', chrs$endsnp)
```

or using `paste` and specifing the separator between the strings

```
chrs$endsnp = paste('end', chrs$endsnp, sep='')
```