# GBP currency signs in R

Tags: r, currency

I am trying to apply a pound sign to my data - this is my code:

```
      test <- cc %>%
               group_by(cat, Region) %>%
               summarize(vf = sum(vf)) %>%
               spread(cat, vf) %>%              
    mutate_at(vars(-Region,), funs(. %>% round(0) %>% scales::dollar()))
```

This obviously returns dollar signs for my values - I am looking to apply pound signs. What's should I be inputting instead of dollar to achieve this? I've tried pound, sterling, GPB

Comment: press alt 0163 on the numerical keyboard for the `£` sign

Comment: Related post - "add any prefix" - https://stackoverflow.com/q/24055308/680068

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scales::dollar` has a default `prefix` argument as `'$'`.

```
scales::dollar(1000)
#[1] "$1,000"
```

You can change the `prefix` to `'£'` for your case.

```
scales::dollar(1000, prefix = '£')
[1] "£1,000"
```