# Add a word as a prefix to each value of a variable

Tags: r

I'm looking to change existing data in a column.
The data looks like

```
Location
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
```

And I would like to change the data like

1 <- "Station 1"

2 <- "Station 2"

3 <- "Station 3"

and so on

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a prefix to all rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055308/add-a-prefix-to-all-rows-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `paste`

```
df1$Location <- paste("Station", df1$Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option is `sprintf`

```
transform(
  df,
  Location = sprintf("Station %s", Location)
)
```

which gives

```
    Location
1  Station 1
2  Station 1
3  Station 2
4  Station 2
5  Station 3
6  Station 3
7  Station 4
8  Station 4
9  Station 5
10 Station 5
```